# spring-cloud.version to be used for spring boot version 2.6.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-consul

Spring-boot-starter-parent version:2.6.6
I want to know the required spring-cloud.version and also the spring-cloud-starter-consul-config dependency in detail.

I have imported some sample Maven project to go through spring consul.

The spring-boot-starter-parent version is 2.6.6 and i tried using spring-cloud.version 2021.0.0 and also 2022.0.0 and after adding spring-cloud-starter-consul-config dependency, i am unsure of which version to be kept there.

Comment: Now if only there was a [compatibility matrix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud).